# How Elasticsearch work with index life cycle if we use routing key with search/writing query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am new in ES and as per my understanding, If we use a routing key with document insertion it will help to store that doc into a particular shard and the same routing key will provide help during searching, our search query will directly reach to the particular shard.

Now if we use ES index the life cycle and let's suppose after 3 days if we move data from hot to warm.

1. In this case what ES will re-index data and store it with different shards?
2. If **yes** then how the routing key will help to search data because the doc moves to another shard?
3. If **No** then how ES will manage Read only with the same shards and same doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index Lifecycle Management doesn't reindex data when moving the indexes from hot to warm, the indexes are just moving from hot nodes to warm nodes, shards are left untouched

So it's a non-issue because everything you've indexed will stay the same way all along the lifecycle, no rewriting is done. And if you [shrink your index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ilm-shrink.html) between the hot and warm phases, the all documents written to a given shard with the same routing key, will keep being co-located on the same shard after the shrink operation.